# MySQL connection ip changes from the specified ip address

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ip-address

I have a MySQL database running on a networked computer. I have had no trouble connecting to it in the past. Suddenly, however (after a restart and a weekend), I get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'x.x.x.y'.
```

This is exceptionally odd as I am trying to connect by:

```
mysql -h x.x.x.x -u root
```

For some reason my the ip address (the final couple digits after the last '.') I am attempting to connect to changes from what I type in.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10.

EDIT: The remote connection is up and ping-able. Mysql is also function properly on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address/hostname you type in after the `-h` flag is that of the MySQL server you are connecting to.  The IP address/hostname in your error message is that of the computer you are connecting from.  Likely you had a change in a dynamically-allocated IP address and your user account is not set up to allow access from that account.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. It was a bit more confusing than normal as I was originally connecting through a router on a subnet, but then swapped out the router and could still connect fine. However, apparently my address changed, and so I didn't recognize the error as referring to my own ip. Thank you.

Comment: I have experienced the same thing, but I'm using GCP instances with static IP addresses.  The IP of the compute instance is whitelisted with the db instance.  Indeed, I can - as the apache user on the compute instance - successfully connect to mysql on the db instance.  However, when I try to do this through my site, i get an error message similar to the OP with the local ip listed.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

```
You will need to reset the password.

First start the mysql server instance or daemon with the --skip-grant-tables option. (security setting)

Then Execute these statements.
# mysql -u root mysql
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_new_password') where USER='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Finally, restart the instance/daemon without the --skip-grant-tables option.

You should be able to connect with your new password.

# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: your_new_password`enter code here`

Hope this helps.
```